# Using CiviMember to automatically create a Drupal user

Tags: drupal, civimember, civicrm-entity

I am relatively new to Drupal (I using version 7) and CiviCRM.  I have set up a website in which members will be entered manually, rather than using an online signup form.

I am envisaging the workflow to be:

1. Admin user logs on to Drupal website and goes to CiviCRM
2. They create a Membership for a Household
3. For each member of that Household, they create a related Contact

At this point, I want a new Drupal user to be created for each Contact, so that they can log in to certain restricted parts of the website.

All the documentation I have seen so far shows it working the other way around - creating a Drupal user causes the creation of a CiviCRM contact.

So, is what I am asking to do possible and does it make sense in the Drupal/CiviCRM context.

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 4):

This can work -> when on the Contact Summary View -> under Actions -> an Admin can create a user account for that Contact;

And then to Automate this workflow: you can use CiviCRM Entity module + Drupal Rules configured to create a Drupal user account when a Membership (of specific id) has been added;

Working example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was wondering if there was a way for Drupal/CiviCRM to do this automatically?

Comment: Added that in above for you;

Comment: Added a working example of such a rule above