# create an Drupal core account when using a webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, user-account

I would like to create a Drupal user account when a user becomes a member via a webform. Ideally a user would get redirected from the webform to a profile, but I do not think this is possible?

I have come across this article, which was written over 5 years ago, is it still valid? https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and

It seems like it would work, but for ease would this workflow be suitable?

1. User applies for account via a profile/Drupal core registration form (Payment pending group/role gets assigned)
2. Edit some template files so the site checks for current role assigned to a user and displays a message informing they have finalise the membership process and pay if they have the Payment pending role.
3. User is directed to a webform and pays.
4. User is removed from Payment pending and Added as a full member

I'm sure both solutions would work. It would be great to hear from other people who have more experience with Civi.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drupal Rules to create the Drupal User for a contact when they get a Membership status of 'x'.

Here is one that KarinG has shared before [Using CiviMember to automatically create a Drupal user](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/using-civimember-to-automatically-create-a-drupal-user/24163)

Thank you Karin

Comment: I have posted a detailed example of such on SE previously - perhaps a few months ago

Comment: Found it -> https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/using-civimember-to-automatically-create-a-drupal-user/24163

Comment: Marvellous - wondering how we could better tag these for future searchers.

Comment: Yeah I had troubles finding it myself :-)

Comment: That was why i went for the Fuzion Treasure Trove approach of adding example code to a quick blog with taxonomy so easy to find ;-) But I don't think to add everything there that I explain on here. But better to have on here than in Chat where things really disappear without trace

Comment: Thank you Karin and Pete! I will spend the next day or 2 implementing the above and report back how I got on. Thanks agin.

Comment: Hi, I got the rule working without too much difficulty. I'm still pretty new to rules so a bit of learning took place. There are 2 small issues

1: I can't figure out what the rule is in the conditions part. Can you point me in the right direction? Is the condition checking if the user already exists in Drupal core?

Comment: 2: I want to assign the membership to the organisation. When I do this the username which gets generated is the payment card information firstname_surname. This leads the thread onto a greater scope than my initial question. Does it matter who the membership sits with (induvial or organisation?) as I have added the relationship type in:

Administer  CiviMember  Memebership Types

I feel like I’m getting so close to putting this site into production! Thank you for your help

Comment: i haven't tried building a Rule that is based on Inherited Membership but in general you want an individual to be the User so that is the route I would be looking down if i were you

Answer (score 0):

This rule seems to work when a relationship is added. I have added an extra to to select the type of relationship, as there are multiple on the webform:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more - I don't follow how this is an Anwer to your own Question since the Q had no reference to Relationships, but only talked about Memberships. COuld you pls edit your question to make it clearer what you were trying to achieve - it will help others who come along in your wake