# Membership renewal for organisations - how to remove: On Behalf Of Organization

Tags: civimember

I have setup a webform for an organisation to become a member, this process also makes a Drupal user. I roughly followed [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/using-civimember-to-automatically-create-a-drupal-user/24163).
The membership is with the organisation, the Drupal account is also created with the organisation email address. It might be worth noting that there are also 2 individual contacts created during this process.

1: Main Contact for the organisation
2: Representative for the organisation

When the organisation signs into Drupal and renews their membership the user is asked for this information: On Behalf Of Organization.

As the membership is for this organisation I don't want the user to see this. How do I remove this?

[image]

Comment: Found the answer. Turn off: on behalf of an organisation in the Contribution Page. I would still be interested in any opinions to my approach for this setup. After all, there are many ways to skin a cat.