# Membership dashboard issue caused using webform for membership signup

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, dashboard, user-dashboard

I am having an issue with the member dashboard when users signup for their membership via a webform. I roughly followed [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/using-civimember-to-automatically-create-a-drupal-user/24163) to setup the webform/Drupal signup process. The membership is assigned to the organisation. An individual is also created as the contact person.

I cannot get all of the data showing in the users dashboard at the same time. Depending on which contact is first in the webform CIVICRM section (either the individual or organisation).

- If the organisation is first the contribution shows and nothing else (Membership and contacts)
- If the individual is first the membership and contacts shows (contributions don't show)

For more information I have attached 3 screen captures:

1. User account where organisation was first in the webform
2. User account where organisation was second in the webform
3. The webform area where either organisations or individuals are created

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you were using a civi contribution page, and using the 'on behalf of' then it would be assumed that Ind was the 'current employee' of the Org. not sure if that will change anything in the webform as it makes no sense why the FIrst and Last name fields are not showing

Comment: Adding 'on behalf of' to the contribution page with the organisation first is the webform displays all the information in the dashboard. This creates a couple of other problems. The individual isn't always an employee - although it looks like this relationship wasn't added. And when the user renews their membership they need to complete the On Behalf Of Organization form.

Comment: sorry you have lost me on the nuances. perhaps you could clarify the exact outcome you want/do not want?

Comment: To register an org as a member and to allow the main contact to login and renew/manage the membership. I think it might now be working... not 100% sure what I did. If I find out I will report back. Thanks.